# how to support HA in wso2IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Assume I have one ESB server and connect to two WSO2 Identification server, IS1 and IS2. 
Customer A first login in WSO2 IS1 via ESB. Later WSO2 IS1 is shutdown for maintenance. Can IS2 still process authorization for Customer A without requiring customer A login again?

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking about login to management console of the WSO2 Identity Server? Say, If two nodes of Identity Server are fronted by a LB (Such as ESB or Apache HTTPD..),  The first requirement is that, LB must support for sticky session. Then users can login to management console without any issue..

As sticky session, user requests always send to one node only...If that node is down, then LB needs to send the user request to another node. As there is no session replication between nodes, you may need to re-login again...  Basically as WSO2 products do not support for session replication across nodes,  you can not achieve seamless HA,  when login to management console..   I guess WSO2 have some plan to support session replication in the future.. .

But, if you are taking about accessing admin services of Identity Server, you can still have seamless HA. Say, from ESB,  you are talking Admin service API of the WSO2 Identity Server. You can find more details about load balancing admin service from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2014/03/04/load-balancing-wso2-admin-services/). I guess this would be useful for you.